# Parameter String fails with TypeError: Pipeline variables do not support __str__ operation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

ParameterString is failing in the default_value step where I am passing with the S3 bucket path. Do we have any other way to represent the S3 path in parameter string.

```
 batch_data_name = ParameterString(
 name=batch_data_name,
 default_value=f"s3://{default_s3_bucket}/cf-batch-input/{batch_data_name}.txt",
 )
```

TypeError: Pipeline variables do not support **str** operation. Please use `.to_string()` to convert it to string type in execution timeor use `.expr` to translate it to Json for display purpose in Python SDK

File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipelines/cf_model/pipeline.py", line 469, in get_pipeline
default_value=f"s3://{default_s3_bucket}/cf-batch-input/{batch_data_name}.txt",

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I would venture a guess that in your code `batch_data_name` is not a string, but a different object (e.g., `ParameterString`).  The interpreter is trying to apply this object's internal `__str__` method to convert it into a string and fails.

Please verify that `batch_data_name` is indeed a string at this point in your code.